# Fullscreen overlay click anywhere to close conflicts with text links within overlay

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click

I have a full screen overlay for an About page, which sits over the content of the site when called.
I'd liek the user to be able to click anywhere to close the overlay. However, this conflicts with hyperlinks within the about text. So if I click on a hyperlink within the overlay, it'll close the overlay, and then go to the hyperlink.
How can I separate the hyperlinks from that which is not a hyperlink?

here is a jsfiddle to demo the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/USzAb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to stop click event propagation on all hyperlinks inside #ablock

```
$("#ablock a").click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some code such as...

```
$('#ablock').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzPfQ/).

The problem you're having is the `click` event is bubbling up through ancestor elements, until it triggers the `#ablock`'s `click` event as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the click on the hyperlink bubbles up to the overlay. You will need to stop this bubbling with something like

```
$('a', '#ablock').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()})
```

This will still allow the link click to function and stop the event being handled by you overlay click handler.

I have tested this by adding it to your demo on jsfiddle

Comment: I wrote it while you were posting yours :-)